# How to generate public url for a file in firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Is there any way to generate a public url for a pdf file from firebase storage. The url it gives me right now is [this](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/techmlearnings.appspot.com/o/pdfs%2FUMLNotationSummary.pdf?alt=media&token=628793c2-66e1-42c4-82fe-8b797a08fe60)

But we can see this contains a token and this means there is some session/authentication involved.

Comment: It is public, not guessable, but public. I'm able to see your pdf content. :)

Comment: yes, thanks was just confused by the token field and the url didn't load into  my webview control.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The token is not an authentication token, nor is it for any session management, it's simply for obfuscation.  All these URLs are public, and can be revoked and new tokens generated through the console.

Comment: Great answer Simon!

Comment: I'd appreciate if you can please accept the answer, OP.

Answer (score 5):

You can delete the token, still get access to the file.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/techmlearnings.appspot.com/o/pdfs%2FUMLNotationSummary.pdf?alt=media

I don't know why if I delete "alt=media", it doesn't work

Comment: It seems that without the token it would obey the authentication rules defined in the FireBase console. You're able to access that file because the owner allows read access to anyone. Using the url with the token, bypasses the authentication rules and let you access the file even if the rules forbid it (which is a bit scary IMO).

Comment: this doesnt work for me - not sure if this answer is outdated or not.  Ive changed my rules to the folder to be open to the public as well